# Toggle map markers including inside a cluster

Tags: google-maps

I have a google maps working on a site, the map includes the following:

3 different types of map pins
The pins are also clustered when too close together.

How ever I have now hit a problem:
I have been tasked with now offering the ability of toggling the visibility of each marker group the problem is.. This would be straight forward if the markers were not clustered and following code works just fine:

```
    onOff = (onOff == 1) ? sawdays.accordion.map : null;


    var mapArray;
    switch( type ){
        case 'bandb': mapArray = sawdays.accordion.bandbMarkers;
        break;

        case 'hotel': mapArray = sawdays.accordion.hotelMarkers;
        break;

        case 'inn': mapArray = sawdays.accordion.innMarkers;
        break;

        case 'pub': mapArray = sawdays.accordion.pubMarkers;
        break;
    }

    if ( mapArray.length > 0 ) {
        for (i in mapArray)
            mapArray[i].setMap(onOff);
        }
    }
```

The problem is however, the pins from within the clusters are not toggled, if I switch off say the hotel pins, click a cluster, the Hotel map pins are still there...

I found the following ref on clusters: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html But cannot see a way of achieving what I am after.

I think I have a hit a wall here and that the best way to keep the functionality of the clusters but adding the functionality of the toggles would be to redraw the map (this is the site http://www.sawdays.co.uk/special-places/content/search/?map#maptypeid=roadmap&zoom=9&lng=-3.36493113281245&lat=54.874929190748624 ). The data for the map is ajaxed in on page load so all the data is already there on the clients machine to reconfigure the maps...

**The question:**
Is it possible to toggle the visibility of maps pins from both in and outside of a cluster?

Answer (score 0):

The MarkerClusterer controls the visibility of the markers that it clusters (so you can't control them independently)

My suggestion:

1. keep different arrays for each of your categories
2. when you "hide" a category either remove those markers from the MarkerClusterer or clear the MarkerClusterer and just add the arrays of categories that are visible.
3. To "show" the category add those markers back to the MarkerClusterer or clear the MarkerClusterer and just add the arrays of categories that are visible.
4. Hide/Show the markers that aren't clustered (actually, this probably isn't necessary if you do 1, 2 & 3 correctly)

Comment: Thnaks for the tip.. however if I delete group a from all clusters, how would I toggle them in again... would I have to redraw all the clusters again? At the moment, all the clusters are stored in independant arrays.